# BIRT Reporting: Image Display

Tags: java, birt

I've a BIRT report which is linked to a DataSource.
I want to have a checkbox with Yes & No value and based on one field of Checkbox, i want to generate report in which either Yes or No is checked based on the value of DataSource's field.

I am trying to get the value and then putting it under IF loop and checing if it is true, then i want a image to be displayed in that field where YES is written(over YES)

I'm new to BIRT report.Please tell me how to do it. I have no clue

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i've created 2 label with YES and NO. Tried to put code in Script tag, it is not changing. How to display image on that label

Comment: I think you need to post some code, only relevant parts and then explain clearly what is currently happening and what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I cant post the code :( ... I've to create a Checkbox which has |YES|NO| options and repost should be created with either one of these checked based on the value from DataSource. I've extracted the value from datasource and then i've applied a if/else loop and inside that loop i am trying to display a image over YES or NO, but the code is not working and i think the script is not right. Please let me know what code will give me the desired result

Comment: This question does not show the level self solution attempts expected on SE.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a table and then put dynamic text into a cell with the if statement that reads from a another column or directly from the dataset...

1. Make a dataset from the datasource.
2. Make a 3 column table with values you want to display, for example...
   order_number
   image 
   STATUS
3. Add BIRT "dynamic text" to the image cell and bind that "dynamic
   text" to the data you want to use.
4. Use the Expression builder to make something like the following to load an external image (better to load an embedded image in your report but this works as a quick example).

to read from the Status column of the table...

```
if (row._outer["STATUS"]=="Shipped") {
"<img src='http://example.com/checked.png' >"
}else if (row._outer["STATUS"]=="Cancelled") {
"<img src='http://example.com/not_checked.png' >"
}
```

if you are not displaying the value in an existing table column...

```
if (row["STATUS"]=="Shipped") {
"<img src='http://example.com/checked.png' >"
}else if (row["STATUS"]=="Cancelled") {
"<img src='http://example.com/not_checked.png' >"
}
```